# How to capture data between two string markers python

Tags: python, python-3.7

below is some contents from my log file

```
-- TEST DONE!!! --
-------------
Diff Coverage
Diff: origin/
-------------
a1
a2
-------------
Total:   54 lines
Missing: 41 lines
Coverage: 24%
-------------
Source files without UT:
1. 
2. 
3. 
4. 
5. 
6. 
7.
```

I would like to capture the contents between the "-----------" marker
The contents will be appended into a list named List=[]
Eg:
List = ['Diff Coverage', 'Diff: origin/', 'a1', 'a2', 'Total:........]

I've tried to use loop to obtain those contents,

```
 while True:
                Line=RF.readline()
                Line=Line.strip('\n')
                if not Line:
                        continue

                if Line == r"-- TEST DONE!!! --":
                        continue

                if Line == r"-------------":
                        while True:
                                Line=RF.readline()
                                Line=Line.strip('\n')
                                print(Line)

                                if re.search(r"Total:", Line) is not None:
                                        List.append(Line)
                                if re.search(r"Missing:", Line) is not None:
                                        List.append(Line)
                                if re.search(r"Coverage:", Line) is not None:
                                        List.append(Line)
                                if Line == r"Source files without UT:":
                                        List.append(Line)
                                        break
```

I'm kinda stuck to get all the datas. Thanks for advance for the help

Comment: Removing "-------------" from your log file and reading from file should work.

Comment: No. The log files are generated every day and the script will be automated to capture the data

Comment: Please check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the lines which starts with '--' from the log and append it to the list.

```
data = []

with open('test') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not line.startswith('--'):
            data.append(line)

print(data)
```

Comment: I already called a function to read the log file. 
The portion of the code I provided will only read each line in the log file and capture the data

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one line solution.

***Code:***

```
with open(path_to_logfile) as file:
    print ([a.strip() for a in file.readlines() if not a.startswith("--")])
    #This will return list of values removing starting char "--" and strips \n
```

***Output:***

`['Diff Coverage', 'Diff: origin/', 'a1', 'a2', 'Total:   54 lines', 'Missing: 41 lines', 'Coverage: 24%', 'Source files without UT:', '1.', '2.', '3.', '4.', '5.', '6.', '7.']`

***Links:***:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-comprehension-and-slicing/

Answer (score 0):

You can manupulate your txt file data with below code. This code covers:

1. Multiple block (TEST DONE, Total, Missing, Coverage) in a single file.
2. This code won't work if the loopup values order will change.
3. I assumed that Total, Missing and Coverage will always have a digit (0 or positive values).

**Code**:

```py
import re

#Get the file content into list
with open ("yourFile.txt", "r") as myfile:
    log_messages_list = myfile.readlines()

#Looping true lines (when find "TEST DONE" in line continue with "Total:, Missing:, Coverage:")
foundDone = False
tmpDict = {}  #It will hold temporary values as {'Total': number, 'Missing': number, 'Coverage': String}
for line in log_messages_list:    
    if foundDone == False:
        if "TEST DONE" in line:
            foundDone = True
    else:
        if "Total:" in line:
            tmpDict['Total'] = int(re.findall(r'\d{1,}', line))
        elif "Missing:" in line:
            tmpDict['Missing'] = int(re.findall(r'\d{1,}', line))
        elif "Coverage:" in line:
            tmpDict['Coverage'] = str(re.findall(r'\d{1,}%', line))
            foundDone = False
            yourMasterList.append(tmpDict) #Put all results into a master list
            tmpDict.clear()
```

**Output**:

```
[{'Total': 54, 'Missing': 41, 'Coverage': '24%'}]
```